# Can a HP Pavilion dv7-6130ez run Hyper-V?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hp-pavilion, hyper-v

I need a laptop as a test machine for Hyper-V, nothing fancy. I found this one:

[HP Pavilion dv7-6130ez](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02902328&cc=ad&dlc=en&lc=en&jumpid=reg_r1002_caen)

The general specs (8 GB memory, 1 TB disk) seem very sufficient for my purposes and the CPU (2 GHz Intel Core i7-2630QM) is listed by Intel as supporting both x64 and VT-x:

[Intel](http://ark.intel.com/products/52219/Intel-Core-i7-2630QM-Processor-%286M-Cache-2_00-GHz%29)

Is that all I have to pay attention to and/or can somebody confirm that this laptop will be able to run Hyper-V and Windows Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the CPU Supports Intel or AMD VT, and there is enough memory, you should be good to go. Weather its supported or not is a different story... you may have problems (YMMV) when it comes to graphics drivers and wifi drivers.